Detecting DRM encrypted files
My company uses DRM software (NASCA) for file encryption/protection that is hooked deep into the OS. I'd like to detect whether a file has been encrypted or not, in Python.
An easy way would be checking for whether the file begins with <## NASCA DRM FILE - VER1.00 ##> as all of our encrypted files do.
However, due to the DRM software rules, when reading a DRM'd file into Python (as in open(file, "rb") as handle:), Python may or may not receive the unencrypted file. Thus, in these circumstances, I cannot check for the existence of the NASCA header.
Is there some other way or trick to read a DRM'd file (in Python) and ensure it that it remains encrypted?

Can you check whether an encrypted file has an Alternate Data Stream using e.g. streams?

This sort of hackerish DRM software is never reliable, fundamentally. As far as Python is concerned, that file is unencrypted because the DRM software did actually decrypt the file. The header isn't there, independent of the way you read the file. Now, from a device driver you could see the raw bytes on disk, but you can't write those in Python. Plus, those tend to interfere with the whole DRM idea.
